How to add dependency injection for DbContext to switch the connection in web api
I have an ASP.NET Web API project on .NET 4.8. I have a DbContext as follows:
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace myApp.Models;

public partial class BMAModel : DbContext
{
    public BMAModel()
        : base("name=BMAModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {         
    }
}

I have an interface for the business logic where I am calling data access and from there I am calling this model.
This my DAL class:
public class EMP_DAL
{
   public async Task<string> GetDepartmentById(int Id)
   {
        var model = new BMAModel();
        return await model.Departments
                          .Where(d => d.Dept_Id == Id)
                          .Select(d => d.dept_name.Trim())
                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}

I have an interface for BLL
public interface IDept_BLL
{
    Task<ResponseDTO<string>> SomeMethod(ModelDTO modelDto);
}

Implementation is as follows
public class Dept_BLL : IDept_BLL
{
      private readonly EMP_DAL _dal;

      public Dept_BLL()
      {
          _dal = new EMP_DAL ();
      }

      public async Task<ResponseDTO<string>> SomeMethod(ModelDTO modelDto)
      {
          _dal.SomeMethod(modelDto);
      }
}

I am calling this from my controller as follows
public class MyController : ApiController
{
      private readonly IDept_BLL _iDept_BLL;
    
      public MyController ()
      {
         var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddSingleton<IDept_BLL , Dept_BLL ().BuildServiceProvider();
        _iDept_BLL = serviceProvider.GetService<IDept_BLL>();
      }

      [Route("api/CreateEmployee")]
      [HttpPost]
      public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateEmployee([FromBody] Employee_DTO empDto)
      {
            var response = await Task.Run(() => _iDept_BLL.SomeMethod(empDto));
            return Ok(response);
      }
}

As of now everything is working fine, now I got a requirement where I need to change the connection based on some conditions. Instead of changing the entire logic in DAL is there a simple way to switch the connection from one to another. I will have multiple connections but the table structure is same for all.
I have this in my model, but not sure how to call it
public BMAModel (string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }


Usually we switch the whole DBContext and not the connection. The question is also unclear about the change. Change at compile time or runtime? Change and switch back or change for only some operation?

run time for all operations

I will pass the required database name as enum so that I can get the required connection from the config file. Based on that whold dcontext should be switched

I notice that DI container is being used, but there's no "injection" at all. For example, the constructor of Dept_BLL should accept EMP_DAL as a parameter, and the same goes for every private instance. When it is done like that, switching of the DbContext can be done in the DI registration part.

You are saying on this right? public Dept_BLL()
{
_dal = new EMP_DAL ("");
}

Here is the sample repo I am trying  https://github.com/Github743/DependencyInjection. I will have multiple connection strings in config, I need to do minimal change in BLL or DAL so that the connection string will be changed
